# How to take or choose image from gallery in IONIC 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How to take an image from the gallery in IONIC 3?

I am failed to take image from gallery using

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera-preview/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can do it using [**Native camera plugin**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/).

*.ts*

```
 //take Photo
  takePhoto(sourceType:number) {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      correctOrientation: true,
      sourceType:sourceType,
    }

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
    }, (err) => {
      // Handle error
    });
  }
```

**Note:** You just need to call above method like:

`this.takePhoto(0);//photo library`

`this.takePhoto(1);//camera`

`0` for `photo library` `1` for `Camera`

*UI*

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that those `sourceType` values are available as constants, which can make your code more descriptive:
`this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA` and `this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY`

Comment: how to select multiple images??

Comment: how to select multiple images??

Comment: You can use this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/image-picker/ @AnkitMaheshwari

Comment: @Sampath - that does not open image gallery (folders to select images) instead it just open all images together which becomes very difficult to scroll and find the desired images.

Comment: For me, when I click on the gallery option nothing happens

Comment: @AnandRaj Please open a new question with your code.

Answer (score 3):

Following the most vote answer, a quick snippets.

Define 2 options types:

```
  private optionsCamera: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 100,
    targetWidth: 600,
    sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
  }

  private optionsGallery: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 100,
    sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
  }
```

and when you call you method **getPicture** from camera

replace options object for the proper situation.

This is for camera

```
this.camera.getPicture(this.optionsCamera).then((imageData) => {
  let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
 }, (err) => {
  // Handle error
  console.log(err)
 })
```

This is for gallery

```
this.camera.getPicture(this.optionsGallery).then((imageData) => {
  let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
 }, (err) => {
  // Handle error
  console.log(err)
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
TakeCamera() {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      this.base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      this.photos.push(this.base64Image);
      this.photos.reverse();
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please use Markdown formatting.  Also, please explain why/how this solves the problem, in English.

Answer (score 0):

Use image picker plugin:

```
getImage(){
let options = {
maximumImagesCount:1//select number of image default is 15
}
this.imagePicker.getPictures(options).then((results) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
  }
}, (err) => {
console.log("error: "+err); 
});
}
```

Ref [image picker](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/image-picker/)